# GPG key server for internal network

Tags: gpg

I'm looking for some software that works just like the public key servers but will only serve keys for a local network, hence the server needs to not sync with the public network.

Can anyone suggest any software that can do this and how to configure it so it doesn't sync with the public network?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using onak for that. I don't find it very stable, but it does the job anyway. It doesn't sync with public servers by default, and you can integrate the add/update/search cgi scripts in a web interface of your choice.

Comment: Any other options? Preferably something stable.

Comment: Nope, that's the only option I know, and I've searched quite a bit. Did you test onak?

Comment: 6 years later - any new alternatives now ?

Comment: I haven't had that need since, so I never investigated anything else than Onak.